# Display the post content in text widget on click of a post item in a Post Grid Widget in Elementor

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, elementor

Currently, I am using Elementor(Pro) and I have a post grid. It only displays images, titles, and excerpts. When you click an item or the image thumbnail, it will redirect you to the page of the post and display the post content of the clicked post. Now, I am looking for a way to dynamically display the contents of the clicked post just below the post grid without redirecting the user to another page. Can anyone suggest a way for me to implement this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by creating a custom loop in the them builder using the [Elementor Custom Skin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ele-custom-skin/) plugin.

It gives you the ability to customize how the posts are displayed in a post grid, after you created your custom loop, you can use the template by selecting it in the skin dropdown you see in layout section.

You can find a lot of videos about it on YouTube, this is an example:

[How to display posts in Elementor Pro with your own Design (Elementor Custom Loop)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7QRFgw4DCo)